Armature duplicates when I move rigged bones
I have a scanned sculpture that I am trying to adjust. When I move the bones in pose mode it moves them, very slowly, but leaves a copy of the original pose in that location. I've tried decreasing the number of faces in the mesh but am stuck. I'm new to blender so any advice please please go step by step :)


Hello, maybe you have duplicated the faces of your mesh? in Edit mode put your mouse cursor on the mesh, press L and move the mesh to see if this is the problem

Could you give some more information. Maybe include screenshots or attach your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/

@dgc I just added the blend file!

You have overlapping faces, you can't fix it because the overlapping faces are part of the same mesh and the vertices don't overlap so you can't just do a simple merge by distance, also some faces are inverted, and more generally the topology is very bad, you should retopologize your mesh, and I'm not sure you can do it with any remesh tool, you may need to do it manually. As the shape is pretty simple it should be rather easy.
